# Getting a DIV to affect its previous element height?

Tags: css

I currently have something like the following:

[image]

Basically it's just three divs contained in one `container_div` which has its width and height specified. CSS code for the container and the top div looks like:

```
.container_div{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
}

.top_div{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

What I am now trying to do is come up with CSS code for the `center_div` and `bottom_div` elements in a way that:

- Bottom div has no overflow
- Bottom div can grow/shrink without causing its parent element to change its size ( something like bottom:0 absolute positioning )
- Whenever bottom div grows, center div shrinks and vice-versa.

This is what should happen when bottom div grows:

[image]

I am looking for a pure CSS solution. Firefox support is enough.

Comment: Post all html and css you got so far. Even beter make a JSfiddle.

Comment: What are the conditions? Can parent div grow? Does bottom div allow scroll?

Comment: Actually no. Parent dimensions are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by a css table layout. In your case, involving table rows, that will (by default) automatically fill the space of it's `display: table` container.

In your case, just set:

- The top div to be a fixed height
- The middle div to be 100% height. This will squize the bottom div to its own content height.
- The bottom div to be zero height.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

#container {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

#container > div:nth-child(1) {
  display: table-row;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#container > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#container > div:nth-child(3) {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>div 1 (fixed 100px)</div>
  <div>div 2 (expand to fill remaining space) </div>
  <div>
      div 3 (fit its own content)
      loren ipsum dolor sit amet... loren ipsum dolor sit amet... loren ipsum dolor sit amet... loren ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
</div>
```